# List index out of range, and python is lying large CSV

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to take two csv files, that have them same ID number in column 1. Have python look for the match and append the two columns to the matching row in spreadsheet 1. have them look for a match in column one then add the matching rows to the same ID.

```
spreadsheet 1
0001, beth, merda
0002, mike, john
0003, mary, smith
```

spreadsheet 2

```
0001, url, owner
0003, url, owner
0002, url, owner
```

after the amendment

```
0001, beth, merda, url, owner
0002, mike, john, url, owner
0003, mary, smith, url, owner
```

Currently I'm getting an error that:

```
File "payments.py", line 10, in <module>
    if row[0] in first:  # row[0] = clearing solution id
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I run 
    `print(len(first)`
It says 190. So I'm at a loss

```
import csv

#create a dict from first csv, with clearing solution id as key
with open("WEEKLY DDS PAYMENT UPLOADS 3-30-15--4-3-15 (1).csv", "r") as f:
    first = {rows[0]: rows[1:] for rows in list(csv.reader(f))}

# compare second csv and append rank
with open("report1428344317924.csv", "r") as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if row[0] in first:  # row[0] = clearing solution id
            first[row[0]].append(row[1])  # row[1] = rank


# convert dict back to list
merged = [(k,) + tuple(v) for k, v in first.items()]

# write list to output csv
with open('output.csv', "w") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(merged)
```

Comment: Put the statement `print row` just before `if row[0]` to see what's really in the `row` variable. (Hint: It's not something that has any index-accessible elements).

Comment: The error could be due to empty lines in your csv file - have you removed empty lines? You could test this by `print row` after the `for row in csv.reader(f):` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your report file for blank lines. `csv.reader` will return a 0-length sequence on a blank line, so `row[0]` will be out of range. You wouldn't get `IndexError` from `first` anyway, it's a dictionary rather than a list so missing elements would raise `KeyError`.

It's easy enough to skip empty rows if you need to, something as simple as `if row and row[0] in first:` would do it.